# Why items-center not working in tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css, centering

I have this weird issue where `items-center` or `vertical-middle` are not working properly. I have a `navbar` with a `div` and a `ul` list. I am trying to align both of them vertically. It centers the `div` perfectly but doesn't center the `ul`.

If I set `m-auto` to `ul`, it works, but I want to have some margin in `ul`, so I can't do that.

[image: image shows the navbar and the code]

Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: Please post a reproducible code snippet of your issue instead of a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `height` of your `ul`?
Most probably, height of your `ul` is same as that of the `nav`, due to which it is already centered vertically!

If that's the case (as it's not clear in your description), you can do two things:

1. Reduce the height of `ul` to the height of your list items (means no spacing between list items and `ul` vertically, or
2. use `items-center` for `ul` separately to center the items inside `ul` as well!

Hope that helps!